# CMake Error: Unknown CMake command "add_message_files"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
catkin_make --force-cmake 
Base path: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws
Source space: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/src
Build space: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/src -        DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/install" in    "/home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/jackcviers/Development/ros_piksi_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.88
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - piksi_sensor_msgs
-- ~~  - piksi_driver
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'piksi_sensor_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(piksi_sensor_msgs)
CMake Error at piksi_sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:47 (add_message_files):
  Unknown CMake command "add_message_files".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

-- Relevant CMakeLists.txt:

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

ROS: Hydro

Any ideas what is causing this issue? I'd love to show you the cmake file, but for some reason it thinks I'm trying to post a link if I do and I don't have enough karma...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186986/cmake-error:---unknown-cmake-command-%22add_message_files%22./) by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-11-03**:
Hi, this is off topic but I have been searching the forum for solutions for using piksi with ROS. So far I have not been able to find much. It looks as though that is what you are working on here? Did you ever get it to work. Would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add the `message_generation` package to your find_package call if you wish to generate messages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-07-17**:
Thank you so much!

**Comment by [WaliD](https://answers.ros.org/users/35586/walid/) on 2018-06-12**:
Hello, I have added the message generation to the find_package as : find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg), but it keep telling me that add_message_files() directory not found

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-06-12**:
@WaliD it sounds like you have a different problem. Please ask a new question.

**Comment by [WaliD](https://answers.ros.org/users/35586/walid/) on 2018-06-13**:
@ahendrix I have the same error, when I enter the command catkin_make in order to compile the talker and the listener it tells me that add_message_files() directory not found.
I have already added the message generation to find_package, but it tells me the same error

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-06-13**:
The OP was `Unknown CMake command "add_message_files".`, your error is different. Please ask a new question.

**Comment by [WaliD](https://answers.ros.org/users/35586/walid/) on 2018-06-13**:
It is the same error I said, but I have solved the problem: I forget to add the message_generation to the file "package.xml".
Thank you

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2020-06-04**:
@WaliD Hi, Could you please tell me, how did you add 'message_generation' to 'package.xml' and where. any sample, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you done

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)?

The command add_message_files is defined in the catkin include

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-07-17**:
Indeed,
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)